# getPage() function not working

Tags: php, oop

I am following Object oriented programming tutorial.... I did exact same as tutorial but it doesn't work for me at Url class in getPage() function and it does not show any error.

... As tutorial it will come with error.php which is in pages folder, if I don't have any page created at pages folder or that page should come that will I create at pages folder

```
public static function getPage() {
    $page = self::$_folder.DS.self::cPage().".php";
    $error = self::$_folder.DS."error.php";
    return is_file($page) ? $page : $error;
}
```

[Here is my code...](http://pastebin.com/D9Sfhhiw)
 Have any suggestion...
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You seem to be missing a closing curly bracket `}`at the end of your Url class in Url.php

Comment: thanks for replying . I corrected it and same thing... is there any more issues?

Comment: Since it was missing the bracket and you said there was no error, you should take a look at [How do I get PHP Errors to display?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1053424/4577762)

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any errors I can see. If I `echo Url::getPage();` it displays `pages/error.php` Is that the desired effect?

Comment: php displays errors in a log file. Where are you running your php?

Comment: @FirstOne thank you for suggestion.

Comment: @koplocal I run it in chrome browser

Comment: @Jason actually I didn't get what I am missing ...

Comment: You'll need to set up a local server to run PHP code. Install a program called Mamp which will set up a Apache, mysql, php server for you

Comment: @NILSAGOR Can you send me a link to the tutorial you used?

Answer (score 0):

To run PHP, you need to start a server.

There are many ways to do this. One popular solution is to install [mamp](https://www.mamp.info/en/) which has a free version.

Once you have mamp installed there will be a default htdocs directory. You can change this to where your php code is by going to preferences web server and changing document root:

[image: Document Root Preferences]

To see if any php errors have occured, you'll need to go to the logs which can be located: /Applications/MAMP/logs/php_error.log

Note: This is OS X

Comment: I tried at lampp and xampp both localhost and virtualhost. by in   browser or in terminal  error.log should show me error. but I don't get any error And I followed this tutorial [link](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLf140rGNfPsAMp4o0HmF7xMg4-sFWccYY)   and I stuck in getting the right page

Comment: @NILSAGOR What command are you running in the terminal to view errors? Are you running those programs at the same time as they couldn conflict with each other. Best try to stick with one of them.